# Graphical front-end for jmeter

Tags: jmeter, cucumber, soapui

I use jmeter to test REST web services.
For some customers, I'd like a graphical interface to show the flow of a script.
I imagine tiles for each web service call and lines connecting those tiles to show the sequence of the calls. The configuration of each tile is the configuration of the web service call and the configuration of each line is the data from the response of one call passed to the next to be used in the request. I imagine this graph being drawn and configured automatically from an exisiting jmeter script or created manually (and could output the corresponding jmeter script). I'd love to hit run and watch each tile turn green on success and red on failure.

Does anything like this exist for jmeter, soapui, cucumber, other?

Answer (score 1):

+1 for View Results Tree.  This ticks most of your boxes and each call will display green or red after running.  If you want to put together a workflow diagram manually, you could use a free online editor like app.diagrams.net

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box there is no such option (apart from [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) and [View Results in Table](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_in_Table) listeners)

If you want to make run progress information available for external users - consider going for [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html), there are some [metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) which you may find useful in particular:

- `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ok.count` - number of successful samplers of the given name
- `<rootMetricsPrefix><samplerName>.ko.count` - number of not successful samplers of the given name

So you can plot them in [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) like it's described in [How to Use Grafana to Monitor JMeter Non-GUI Results](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results) article